# R not releasing memory after filtering and reducing data frame size

Tags: r, memory, ram

I need to read a huge dataset, trim it to a tiny one, and then use in my program. After trimming memory is not released (regardless of usage of gc() and rm()). I am puzzled by this behavior.

I am on Linux, R 4.2.1. I read a huge .Rds file (>10 Gb) (both with the base function and the readr version). Memory usage shows  14.58 Gb. I do operations and decrease its size to 800 rows and 24.7 Mb. But memory usage stays the same within this session regardless of what I do. I tried:

- Piping readRDS directly into trimming functions and only storing the trimmed result;
- First reading rds into a variable and then replacing it with the trimmed version;
- Reading rds into a variable, storing the trimmed data in a new variable, and then removing the big dataset with rm() followed by garbage collection gc().

I understand what the workaround should be: a bash script that first creates a temporary file with this reduced dataset and then runs a separate R session to work with that dataset. But feels like this shouldn't be happening?